# In php, how do I load txt file as a string?

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains paragraphs of text.  I want to load it as a string in php, and then collect all the e-mail addresses within it as an array.  However, how do I initially load the text file contents as the string?  Restated, I have

```
$string = **WITHIN TEXT FILE "user@domain.com MIME-Version: bla bla bla user2@example.com";
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)/'
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

How do I load the text from the text file into the string variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($url);
```

Check the reference at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Note: for me for a local file i needed to specify an absolute url, e.g. `$fileContent=file_get_contents(__DIR__."/myFile.txt");` 

Also, if it can't find the file $fileContent will `===FALSE`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)!

```
$file_content = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)